# update multiple solutions using powershell

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, powershell

I want to update multiple wsp solutions using powershell

Currently for every wsp file I have a powershell file with the below code

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity CustomWebparts.wsp -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot\CustomWebparts.wsp -GACDeployment
```

I run the powershell and wait for deployment to happen and then run the next powershell script

How can I avoid this and deploy all wsp files in the folder using powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below script, I amend it for update solutions.

```
Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
function WaitForInsallation([string] $Name)
{
        Write-Host -NoNewline "Waiting for deployment job to complete" $Name "."
        $wspSol = get-SpSolution $Name
        while($wspSol.JobExists)
        {
            sleep 2
            Write-Host -NoNewline "."
            $wspSol = get-SpSolution $Name
        }
        Write-Host "Job ended" -ForegroundColor green
}
Function Update-SPSolution ($WspFolderPath)
{
    $wspFiles = get-childitem $WspFolderPath | where {$_.Name -like "*.wsp"}

    ForEach($file in $wspFiles)
    {
        $wsp = Get-SPSolution | Where{$_.Name -eq $file.Name}
        if($wsp -eq $null)
        {
            write-host "Solution already exists"
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "Updating solution"
            Update-SPSolution -identity $wsp -LiteralPath ($WspFolderPath + "\" + $file.Name) -GACDeployment

        }

    }
}
try
{
        Update-SPSolution "C:\EXPORTEDWSP"
}
catch
{
    write-host $_.exception

}
```

Check more about this here [Add multiple farm solutions using power shell (Not Deploy)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38203/add-multiple-farm-solutions-using-power-shell-not-deploy)

Comment: not sure why it didn't work
I just updated the path inside try block

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: there were no errors

I kept getting Updating solution message

But when I went to the solution, the last operation time was not updated as it used to update when I do update solution individually